# What is the best and securest way to execute bat file on a Azure Win VM from outside VM and triggered by an Azure Function

Tags: azure, powershell, batch-file, azure-functions, virtual-machine

There is a Windows VM hosted on Azure. On this VM is a .bat file which I need to execute from outside. The start of this process should be possible within an Azure Function.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

I tried to execute the .bat file via Azure Cloud Shell and it worked but I found multiple commands and I am not sure which is the best one and which are usable in an Azure Function.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can write Azure Functions using Powershell as the programming language. Then, import Az.Compute and use the following to invoke commands in your vm from the Azure Functions:

```
Invoke-AzVmRunCommand `
     -ResourceGroupName "rg-azpsremote" `
     -VMName "server1" `
     -CommandId "RunPowerShellScript" `
     -ScriptPath "C:\temp\x.ps1"
```

ps: you can call the bat file from ps1 file.